# What is the proper way to handle child selection when an ExpandableListView gets focus?

Tags: android, focus, selection, expandablelistview, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have an `ExpandableListView` and then some other control that can have focus to the right of it.  Something like this.  Note: Child2 is selected.

```
Group1       
  Child1    +-----------------------+
 *Child2*   |                       |
  Child3    | Other focusable View. |
  Child4    |                       |
  Child5    +-----------------------+
```

Using the d-pad, if I press right, focus goes to the other view.  At that point if I press left on the d-pad, focus returns to my `ExpandableListView`, but Child3 gets selected instead of Child2 (because it's in the center).

In general, how can I ensure that the previously selected child remains the selected child when focus leaves and then returns to my `ExpandableListView`?  Any ideas on a work around?  I tried caching the current selection then calling `setChildSelected()`, but for some reason the selection doesn't happen.

Comment: how do you handle focus position in expandablelistview? I use onitemselectedlistener but position keep changing whenever different group opened..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved it by caching the current group and child when focus is lost and then explicitly re-setting the group / child when the listview re-gains focus.  I had to also disable the listview and re-enable it in various places.  It's a hack, but it works.